# GIT workflow to split one app into two (While keeping a "core" codebase)

Tags: git

I have decided to create a new app that uses the same core codebase from the original app I have already developed.

The original app will still be worked on.

Should I:

1. Have 3 repositories? i.e. core, old and new. So that core changes can be used on both old and new apps.
2. Just have different branches with the same principle as above?
3. Or, use another method that I have not thought of?

Also, if implementing solution 1, how do I go about apply changes made to core to the 2 other code bases? Which git commands do I use?

Comment: Question: Will one of these new lines of work serve as a "core" for the others?  If so, then it sounds like you maybe want a new branch in addition to the core branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am thinking of splitting it into 3. Core, old and new. Both old and new "branches" out from core. As asked in the question, should I have separate repositories instead of simply branches?

Comment: You don't need a separate Git repo to accomplish this.  I would personally opt for having a core branch and 2 product line branches.